# A generalization of Complement[] which does not remove duplicates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists $A(k,m)$ and $B(k,m)$ given by

```
A[k_, m_] := Prepend[Table[k/m + (l - 1)/(m + 1), {l, 0, m}], 1]
B[k_, m_] := Prepend[Table[(k + l)/m, {l, 0, m - 1}], (m + k)/m]
```

for any choices of $m=2,4,6,\dots$ and $k=1,2,3,\dots,m$.

What I'm trying to do is define new lists $a(k,m)$ and $b(k,m)$, which are the same as $A$ and $B$ except all matching elements have been dropped.  For example, consider

```
In[3]:= A[4, 4]
B[4, 4]

Out[3]= {1, 4/5, 1, 6/5, 7/5, 8/5}
Out[4]= {2, 1, 5/4, 3/2, 7/4}
```

We see each list has a common element of $1$ so in this case we would remove the single element $\{1\}$ from each list to get $a(4,4)=\{4/5, 1, 6/5, 7/5, 8/5\}$ and $b(4,4)=\{2, 5/4, 3/2, 7/4\}$.

If the elements in $A$ and $B$ are unique (no duplicates) then this would easily be implemented as

```
a[k_, m_] := Complement[A[k, m], B[k, m]]
b[k_, m_] := Complement[B[k, m], A[k, m]]
```

Unfortunately, when $A$ or $B$ contains duplicates this method can break down.

Comment: Does using `ResourceFunction["MultisetComplement"]` do what you need?

Comment: @CarlWoll Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing an answer to your now-deleted-question before went for dinner,, but your `flag` won't work if $\mathbf{b}$ starts first, despite `a` and `b` interlace by definition. For your `A` and `B` this isn't a concern being `A<B`, otherwise you could define `flag` as

```
Sort[
    Sign[Sort[r a[K, M] - Floor[r a[K, M]]] - Sort[r b[K, M] - Floor[r b[K, M]]]]
][[{1, -1}]] /. {x_, y_} -> x == y
```

As for the why, the subtraction between lists requires equal length of the lists. However in your `flag`, when $K=M$, `a` and `b` have unequal length, because $1$ appears twice in `A` (one from the `Prepend` and the other when $l=1$) while `B` has one $1$, resulting in unequal length after the set difference applied on `a` and `b` - `A` loses one more element ($1$). I suppose the set difference was to satisfy the disjointness, but for the given parameters, they can't be disjoint for $M=K$. The multiset complement resolves the unequal lengths but disjointness, which defeats the whole purpose. I'd suggest to simply remove the appending `1` for $M=K$, as this is the only case when disjointness fails for your parameters.